# Is it required to enable the Java Access bridge before using the DLL's?

Tags: java, c#, java-access-bridge

I have written an application that makes use of the Java Access Bridge in C#. The JAB isn't really widely covered on the internet and that's why I'm asking here. The JAB is included with Java 7 now but when deploying my application to my users do they need to enable the JAB for my application to make use of the DLL's? When I installed the JAB manually I did not run the command but I can use the library but will it work like this for all of my users that have Java 7 installed?

Answer (score 1):

Your user need to enable JAB before using your application.

If your user are using Java 6 then you need to provide them details of installing JAB 2.0.2. Also make sure your application calls proper JAB DLLs based on 32/64 bit OS.

There are three ways your user can enable JAB.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/access/enable_and_test.html